# How to prevent a user from selection on ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT a location that doesn't support "wa" mode for opening a file descriptor?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I'm using `Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` to let the user select a location to save a file.

Then I open a `ParcelFileDescriptor` to write the file using
`contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(uri, "wa")`

I need to be able to append to this file or at a minimum to write to it starting at a certain `byte`.

This works perfectly fine when saving the file locally but when I try to save it on Google Drive I get an error saying `wa` is not supported.

Is there a way I can prevent the user from choosing a location that won't support `wa` when selecting where to save the file?

Comment: Oh, I wish. [We can't even guarantee write access](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/133539340).

Comment: Oh, that sucks. Thanks for the link.